# Shorthand for unary vs. binary operators

Tags: computer-science, arithmetic-expressions, unary-operator, binary-operators

Is there a convention for denoting a unary plus vs a binary plus, or a unary minus vs binary minus? For example, I'm making something up here, but something similar to the following

- `+` means addition, `(+)` means unary-plus
- `-` means subtraction, `(-)` means unary-negation

Or is there not really a direct notation for this, and it needs to be spelled out?

Comment: Within the context of what?  Are you talking about a grammar?  It's usually absurdly obvious whether it's unary or binary, because of whatever token is on the left.  Or, with prefix syntax like LISP, the tokens that follow.

Comment: @paddy sure, just printing I mean, like if I have a list of tokens I want to print and just want to see what's been detected.

Comment: I don't think there's any specific convention.  Just use whatever makes sense to you.  Normally, the meaning of a token is inferred by processing a grammar.  Read about Flex, Bison, and related tools.